# Redux: Several dispatches vs just one on single page?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My question is more of an architecture question. In my project, once a user signs in they are taken to a home page that has several "widgets". Each widget requires an API call of some sort. Five of them go to my own API and one posts to a third-party API.

I have a loading state in my reducer and each component's render method. The home page is the parent component and each widget is a child component.

Is it better to retrieve all of the data that I need in the parent component, and then pass that data down into each child component? Or is it better to split it all up so that each child component dispatches its own actions and handles its own data?

The first option is a single large hit to my database that includes all of the info I need, the second option is several smaller hits to my database (although the time difference seems negligible to me).

Side note: I originally went the route of the first option, however I was running into issues with my app erroring out because a lot of my data is nested 4+ levels deep. I'm not sure if that means I need to use a library like Normalizr to fix this, or if it is just my ignorance and general lack of knowledge of Redux?

Comment: I think the answer depends on your specific project and APIs/databases. I have a larger web project that replaced a legacy thick client from a vendor. The vendor used lots of small database calls and then processed them which was slow and inefficient in the scheme of things. I aggregated the data using a database view in tSQL and was able to improve performance even though the query hit multiple one to many tables. Performance issues can be on either the server side or the client side and you need to analyze both to determine the best approach.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your comment. Honestly it's just a side project to learn React/Redux better, and I have tried out both options. Either one seems fine, I'm just having issues then taking that data and using it correctly. I may need to post another question with specific code examples...

Comment: posting a little bit of code and sample data would help with a more detailed answer vs theory.

Comment: Each component will get its own "slice" of the state that it needs so personally I think each component should also be responsible for working with that slice i.e. dispatching any actions which have to do with their own part of the application state. Of course this is my opinion and not a fact.

Comment: @apokryfos yeah that totally makes sense

Comment: @SteveB definitely, I suppose I just wanted to see if I was going down the "correct" path to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

> I originally went the route of the first option, however I was running into issues with my app erroring out because a lot of my data is nested 4+ levels deep.

This particular problem can be solved on the server side. *You should always strive to keep your data as flat as possible.* 
Pull the data from your own DB or some third party, mutate it in a way that's easy for client to read and send it back to the client.

> Is it better to retrieve all of the data that I need in the parent
>   component, and then pass that data down into each child component? Or
>   is it better to split it all up so that each child component
>   dispatches its own actions and handles its own data?

I'd say it depends. You can try to get as much stuff as you can that you absolutely need on initial load, without degrading performance. Nothing wrong with components that accept data from a parent component.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Branko. I'm using a Rails API for my backend and jbuilder to send off the JSON, so that's why i was considering using Normalizr to flatten it. I could also look into flattening my data on the jbuilder front, but I know Redux specifically mentions Normalizr in their docs.